# How to monitor java webapplication

Tags: java, monitoring

I want to monitor java webapplication but don't know how to monitor.

1. What is Jave worker process/thread name that I can monitor via perfmon in window or ps -ef in linux ?
2. How to monitor Java worker thread pool ?
3. How to monitor JVM and what counter should I monitor ?

Thanks

Comment: try newrelic if you are willing to pay and want to invest less time.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by monitoring?

Answer (score 2):

for any Java process try JVisualVM. If you need something web-specific you will have to provide more detail

Comment: I want to monitor process cpu/memory usage for Java application. is there no way to monitor directly from perfmon or ps -ef command ?

Comment: If you want to monitor the JVM process on windows you can try Sysinternals Process Explorer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653 . This is IMO as good as it gets on Windows platform. But, i must insist on JVisualVM, it shows a lot more detail on VM internals and resource consumption. I'm pretty sure that's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools to do this. Please have a look jvisualvm that comes with JDK as one of them.

Java process name typically has the word "java" on it

Answer (score 1):

jVisualVM is going to be closest to what you want and is free with the JDK, %JAVA_HOM%/bin/jvisualvm.exe. You will need to use extra JVM options to be able to hook into your webapp (which will also require a restart):

- **-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote**

*Description: enables local access for the JMX agent by registering the JVM instrumentation MBeans and publishing the RMI connector on a private interface*

- **-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port**=3333

*Description: the port used for RMI connections (needs to be an unused port)*

- **-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl**=false

*Description: disables default value of client SSL authentication (easiest/quickest configuration)*

- **-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate**=false

*Description: disables default value of password authentication for remote monitoring*

- **-Djava.rmi.server.hostname**=localhost

*Description: option for the RMI listener (use localhost to have RMI listen locally only or set this to the appserver hostname for remote monitoring)*

Run jVisualVM and select "add new JMX connection" and enter localhost:3333. My favorite extension is thread stack which shows the thread stacks for the currently running threads.